# Need help determining what should be u for the substitution method

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to evaluate the limit:

[image]

I am having trouble determining what should be substituted for u. I was going to substitute z for u so that u=z and du=dx. However this is where I am stuck and confused on what to choose to equal u.

Comment: hint: $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Also some people get messed up by the fractions sometimes. So it may help if you first write it as $\int \ln^9(z) \cdot \frac{1}{z} dz$

Comment: I had a feeling about the ln but what about it being to the power of 9? Would ln^9(x)=1/x^9?

Comment: @JMartinez No. Use the chain rule.

Comment: Also the sub $u=z$ doesn't help transform the integral into anything but what it already is just with a different letter representation for the variable you replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \int u^9 du \text{ where } u=\ln(z)$